# Cannot Open Visual Studio 2013 Express debuggerproxy.dll

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I cannot open Visual Studio Express and have the errors as shown in the attached images.
Please Solve my Problem...
Thank You.
Please Visit the following address for Images.

https://app.box.com/s/37srs5jf6bb0arw4nk5oqmowmk1pb99b

// The Error is generated by SideBySide Source.

Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe". Dependent Assembly debuggerproxy.dll,processorArchitecture="X86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

// Above are the details of the error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023936/why-i-dont-have-microsoft-vc80-mfc-file

Comment: The above thread features the error of "Microsoft.VC80.MFC" whereas I am experiencing from "debuggerproxy.dll".

Answer (score 0):

You could try to open a developer command prompt in admin mode, then type wdexpress.exe /setup

Comment: Still getting the side-by-side error in the developer command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix my issue, but I installed Visual Studio on a Virtual Machine and Worked Easily. I corrupted something because I didn't have enough space on my 'C' drive and tried to smlink or link a directory to 'D' drive and it failed. So, either do it in a Virtual Machine or Format the system.